# Map strange behaviour

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have a map function as follows, which reads from an array of lines generated by a unix command.

```
my %versions =  map {  
  if (m/(?|(?:^Patch\s(?(?=description).*?(\w+)\sPATCH).*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)+).*)|(?:^(OPatch)\s(?=version).*?(\d+(\.\d+)+)))/) 
    { 'hello' => 'bye'; } 
} @dbnode_versions;
```

`print Dumper(\%versions);` gives

```
$VAR1 = {
      '' => undef,
      'hello' => 'bye',
      'bye' => ''
    };
```

which I find extremely odd, as the hello and bye values should only get added if the regex is true. Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: Please show an example of the output from the command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you have to consider what happens when the regex *doesn't* match, and the `if` is false. The `if` will evaluate to some value, although you shouldn't rely on the value of a statement.

Especially, `if (cond) { expression }` is roughly equivalent to `cond and expression`. This means that if the regex (our `cond`) will not match, we'll get a false value.

```
use Data::Dump;
dd [map { /foo(bar)/ and (hello => 'bye') } qw/foo foobar bar/];
```

What is your expected output? You may have thought `["hello", "bye"]`. But actually, we get

```
["", "hello", "bye", ""]
```

because `""` represents the false value returned by the regex match on failure.

If you want to return nothing in failure cases, you should explicitly return an empty list:

```
map { /foo(bar)/ ? (hello => 'bye') : () } qw/foo foobar bar/
```

or use `grep`, which filters a list for those elements that match a condition:

```
my %hash =
    map  { hello => 'bye' } # replace each matching element
    grep { /foo(bar)/ }     # filter for matching elements
    qw/foo foobar bar/;
```

The `%hash` will them either be `()` or `(hello => 'bye')`, as each key can only occur once.

Comment: I don't see how you expect `["", "hello", "bye", ""]`. If the regex matches then `('hello' => 'bye')` is returned; if it fails then `("")` is returned. Unless you mean the result of the `map` if `@dbnode_versions` has three elements, of which only the second matches?

Comment: @Borodin the output `["", "hello", "bye", ""]` is the actual output of the code above it, in contrast to `["hello", "bye"]`. I used a simplified example to keep it reproducible and to avoid the overly long regex in the question.